# R: Extracting numerical values from strings in a column

Tags: r, regex, stringr, data-extraction

I am interested in 1 specific column of a dataframe, where each row contains the name of a neighborhood and a specific number assigned to that neighborhood.

TOR - HOOD - Banbury-Don Mills (42) ( 23.6%)

Please see this image for a better understanding
[neighborhoodnum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUVhi.png)

I only want to extract the first bracketed numbers.
TOR - HOOD - Alderwood **(20)** ( 25.4%)

I have tried using the stringr package but all the functions only take 1 string at a time. There are 140 rows in this column and I want the values from all the row. I am not sure how to go through every string in the column

[Here is what I have tried and the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rsag.png)

and some code I used but got this error (**Error in UseMethod("type") : no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"**)

```
hood_data<-tibble(hood=demo_edu_dataset$Geography)
head(hood_data)

hoodnum<-hood_data %>%
  #separate(hood, into= c("name", "number"), sep = "")
  stringr::str_extract_all(hood_data, "\\d")
```

Thank You

Comment: Maybe `stringr::str_extract(hood_data, "(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\))")`?

Comment: Hi Faria Khandaker. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not post images of code or data here. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). That way you can help others to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hoodnum<-hood_data %>%
 separate(Geography, into= c("name", "number"), sep = "\\(")
```

This worked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `gsub` like below, for example

```
df <- data.frame(X = c("TOR - HOOD - Alderwood (20) ( 25.4%)",
                       "TOR - HOOD - Annex (95) ( 27.9%)"))

df$Y <- as.numeric(gsub(".*?\\((\\w+)\\).*","\\1",df$X))
```

such that

```
> df
                                     X  Y
1 TOR - HOOD - Alderwood (20) ( 25.4%) 20
2     TOR - HOOD - Annex (95) ( 27.9%) 95
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `str_extract` from the `stringr` package as well as positive lookbehind and lookahead:

```
str_extract(YOURDATA, "(?<=\\()\\d{1,}(?=\\))")
```

This regex says: "when you see `(` on the left and `)`on the right, match the number with at least 1 digit in the middle".
If you wrap `as.numeric` around the whole expression, the numbers are converted from character to numeric:

```
as.numeric(str_extract(df$X, "(?<=\\()\\d{1,}(?=\\))"))
```